# What's a good(affordable) business router that can limit traffic to certain machines(ips/ports)?

Tags: router

We are using the basic Verizon router but it sucks so we're looking for a new one that allows us to limit users and our hadoop cluster to certain limits. Our problem is one person can start downloading something and kill the network and every hour we download logs into our cluster but it floods the network unless we rate limit it. Ideally we want to be able to say:

- total: 35 mbps Hadoop Cluster (15
- mbps) Phones (1 mbps) Office(25
- people) (19mbps but no one machine can have more than 5mbps)

Comment: "Affordable" is an extremely subjective thing. Are we talking $100, $1,000,000 or perhaps somewhere in between?

Comment: Well, we're rather small so I doubt I can convince them to spend >$500 on a router when the one we have now "works fine".

Answer (score 1):

If you want cheap, look at the Linksys WRT64GL + third party firmware such as [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato). Total cost probably $70.

It's not built to the same standard as "serious" network equipment but the bang-for-the-buck ratio is tough to beat.

Answer (score 0):

What's "affordable" to you? I'm familiar with Cisco gear so I'd run straight to an ASA5505. For about $2-4,000 (depends on what you get exactly) you can get one installed to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @chris - that asa5505 won't set Ryan back that far.  I was able to outfit three remote offices at about $800 a piece.  Note that the base model is less than that but only supports 10 concurrent users.

Comment: The router needs to be configured, and that doesn't come free (even if he does it himself, somebody's writing his paycheck). I'm making large assumptions about the complexity of his network, so the price may well be <$1000.

Comment: @Ryan, you've got a business where you've saturated a 35Mbps backhaul and management wont spend $1000 on a router. That seems somewhat unlikely. If you really want to run cheap, an old computer running Linux or a BSD can accomplish the same thing. But finding support for such a setup will be expensive at best, maintaining it over time may be difficult, and building a replacement in the event one is needed again may prove difficult. This is an investment in network infrastructure that shouldn't be taken lightly (if it's really warranted).

Comment: Gonna be pedantic here.. The ASA5505 is not a router.  It's a firewall ;)

Comment: @Tom, the ASA5505 is a router too, not just a firewall. The ASA stands for Adaptive Security Appliance, and incorporates VPN, IPS, and Content Security as well. If you're just using it as a firewall, you're scratching the surface of what it can do.

Answer (score 0):

What Verizon router do you have?  I have the ActionTech MI424WR and it does an excellent job with QOS.  You can set DSCP or priority values, and prioritize by protocol, source, or destination.